# Outlook 2013: taskbar envelope notification color

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Upon receiving new mail, Outlook puts a yellow envelope icon beside its normal, blue icon in the taskbar. However, this is not so clear to see for me ... is there any way to change envelope color to red?

Comment: Probably. You would have to find the icon and edit it ...

Comment: Yeah, I know that ... but ... how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not feasible to change the new message icon color using the built-in option within Outlook. As an alternative, you may enable the other options via File > Options > Mail > Message arrival to remind you of the new incoming message:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, already have those options enabled. I am looking to change the color of the envelope, any way, even hard way. :)